# IronPython error on Process.WaitforExit() arguments

Tags: python, ironpython

I am trying to run an external macro using IronPython. sometimes I am bugged by the error :

TypeError: `WaitForExit()` takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

what argument should I insert?

[here](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Launching_Sub-Processes) says nothing is needed

I do :

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
Process.Start(r"C:\python.exe", 'python.py')
Process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not invoking WaitForExit on the Process type instead of an instance? Could you provide a minimal code snippet?

Comment: I think you might be right , I just added the minimal code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit) is an instance method that needs to know which process you are waiting on.
The code needs to be more along the lines of

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
process = Process.Start(r"C:\python.exe", 'python.py')
process.WaitForExit()
```

Assuming a default IronPython installation the following sample shows that the main script actually waits in a more self-contained way (no dependency on installed CPython):

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
ipy = r"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe"
process = Process.Start(ipy, '-c "import time; time.sleep(10)"')
process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this method was not able to make IronPython wait for python to run and finish. the Python.exe window flashed and closed without running

Comment: any idea about this problem ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti please see the added example. I suspect that the spawned process does not successfully execute because the script `python.py` is not found in the working directory or script execution ends unexpectedly.